# create network folder C#

Tags: c#, networking, directory

I have 2 machines EX001 and Ex002 on domain booleanarray.com.
I have credentials of a domain user , (username ABC and password pwd123) to log on to EX002 on domain booleanarray.com.
There is a folder C:\EWS on EX002.

I want to write a C# Windows application that runs on EX001 and creates a new folder under the folder C:\EWS\ on Ex002.
C:\EWS is not a shared folder, but is accessible by ABC when user ABC logs on to EX002.

Can anyone suggest how can I create such a new folder on different computer on same domain in C#?

Answer (score 0):

I won't be able to give you detailed answer. But you probably can first authenticate your windows application on other machine 2 in the domain. Probably you can use ConnectionOptions object. Then you probably can send the command for creating directory to remote machine.

Comment: your answer contains the word `probably` three times.

Answer (score 0):

If c:\ews is not a shared folder, I believe you would need to do it via the administrative share.  So something like:

```
String path = @"\\EX002\c$\EWS\";
Directory.CreateDirectory(path + "new folder name");
```

As the name implies though, this requires that the account have administrative access to EX002.